# Error:INTERNAL firebase functions ,when using it with nodemailer

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, nodemailer, internal-server-error

```js
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
      user: 'xxxxxx@gmail.com',
      pass: 'xxxxxxxx'
    } ,
    tls: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false
  },
  });

  exports.sendMail=functions.https.onCall((req,res)=>{
      cors(req,res,()=>{

        const email=JSON.parse(req.email)
          const mailOptions = {
            from: 'xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com',
            to: email,
            subject: 'Invitation to register your profile in xxxxxxx solutions',
            text: `http://xxxxxx/xxxxxxxx`
          };

          return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
            if (error) {
              return res.send(error);
            }

            return res.send("Email sent")

          });
      })
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

It is most probably because you:

- Use cors within a [Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable).
- Return with `res.send("Email sent")` within a Callable Cloud Function.

So, you should either change to an [HTTP Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events), as follows:

```
  exports.sendMail=functions.https.onCall((req,res)=>{
      cors(req,res,()=>{

        const email=JSON.parse(req.email)
          const mailOptions = {
            from: 'xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com',
            to: email,
            subject: 'Invitation to register your profile in xxxxxxx solutions',
            text: `http://xxxxxx/xxxxxxxx`
          };

          transporter.sendMail(mailOptions)
          .then(() => {
              res.send("Email sent");
          })
          .catch(error => {
              console.log(error);
              res.status(500).send(error);
          });

      })
  })
```

Or modify your Callable Cloud Function as follows:

```
exports.addMessage = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
          const email = data.email;
  
          const mailOptions = {
            from: 'xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com',
            to: email,
            subject: 'Invitation to register your profile in xxxxxxx solutions',
            text: `http://xxxxxx/xxxxxxxx`
          };

          return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions)
          .then(() => {
              return {result: "Email sent"};
          })
          .catch(error => {
              console.log(error);
              throw new functions.https.HttpsError('interna', error.message);
          });
});
```

Also, see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#call_the_function) how to call the Callable CF from your client.